# Quiero hacer que cuando un script especifico se ejecute que la música de fondo pare y que cuando el script deje de ejecutarse que vuelva a sonar

Tags: c#, script, unity, unity2d, sonido

quiero hacer que cuando un script especifico se ejecute que la música de fondo pare unos segundos (unos 30 segundos) y que cuando el script deje de ejecutarse que vuelva a sonar el script es de unity 2d y tengo la música de fondo en un empty object llamado AudioManager y el otro sonido lo tengo ligado a un event system que ejecuta un empty obect llamado attack que ejecuta un script donde el jugador ataca ademas dentro del empty object attack tengo otro audio source con el sonido que quiero que cuando se reproduzca el otro sonido pare

Comment: Cual sería el problema? Lo unico que nos cuentas es tu objetivo.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente lo que necesitas es activar o desactivar el objeto `AudioManager` desde "attack".